# Select from json column

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

There is a task to obtain most ordered products from `orders` table for given period of time. Table have JSON column called `details` and ordered products IDs are stored there:

```json
{
    products: [
        {
            id: 1,
            quantity: 2,
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            quantity: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently, I'm solving it this way, which kind of inefficient:

```php
Order::whereBetween('created_at', $period)
    ->get('details->products as details')
    ->flatMap(fn ($order) => $order->details)
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->map(fn ($products) => $products->sum('quantity'));
```

The result contains pairs, where key - product id, and value total count from orders:

```php
[
    1 => 2,
    6 => 1,
];
```

Is it possible to query product id and quantity directly?

Comment: Please post the structure of related table and sample data.

Comment: @FanoFN table is quite big, but for the query I need only `details` column, which I described. Sample already in my post

Comment: The table is big or data is big? Your query have aggregation and your results return the same value as your sample data. And in the query, you've done a `BETWEEN created_at` and `GROUP BY id` operations which is not in your sample data.

Comment: @FanoFN the sample data is just the content of the json field, whereas the grouping is performed over the Eloquent collection. Anyway:, each product tuple is shown as having id and qty,  the `id`, so there's that

Comment: Have you tried using the [whereJsonContains](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#json-where-clauses) query?

Comment: @Peppermintology, This is not `WHERE` clause but `SELECT`